# Ruby Match Result Not Working on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, heroku, pattern-matching

Using Rails running on Heroku, I've encountered a situation where a regular expression match is found in a string but the $1 variable is not being set for the group in parenthesis. This happens only in my production setup on Heroku, and not on my local system (Rails 3.0.7 with Ruby ruby-1.9.2-p0). The code is

```
puts "**** gateway_reply=#{gateway_reply}"
match = gateway_reply =~ /ID: (\w+)/
msg_id = $1
puts "**** match=#{match}, msg_id ($1) = #{$1}"
```

On my local system, the output is

```
**** gateway_reply=ID: da2x7s5tjumtxtnk1krl8wps4wpasiee
**** match=0, msg_id ($1) = da2x7s5tjumtxtnk1krl8wps4wpasiee
```

On the production system, $1 is not set:

```
**** gateway_reply=ID: 93e4ca3590207761af6f3b5ba3545b36
**** match=0, msg_id ($1) =
```

Any answers as to what is going on here?

Comment: What stack are you using on heroku? Are you sure it matches your development environment?

Comment: You may want to use `\s+` instead of the space in your regex.  A space can be many different values based on environment

Comment: That's a good idea, Michael, though since the expression matches it should still return a value in $1, shouldn't it? Aubrey, the stack is   aspen-mri-1.8.6, * bamboo-mri-1.9.2, bamboo-ree-1.8.7, cedar. Does some version of Ruby have different behavior for return values of matches?

Answer (score 0):

works for me:

```
> gateway_reply='ID: da2x7s5tjumtxtnk1krl8wps4wpasiee'
> gateway_reply.match(/ID: (\w+)/)
> $1
=> "da2x7s5tjumtxtnk1krl8wps4wpasiee"
```

and

```
> gateway_reply =~ /ID: (\w+)/
=> 0
> $1
=> "da2x7s5tjumtxtnk1krl8wps4wpasiee"
```

please note that the result of the match operator `~` is the position of the match